# I want to update to the most recent firmware while jailbroken

Tags: software-update

OK so I have the iPhone 3GS (old bootrom) and am currently on iOS 5.1.1. I'd like to update to the most recent firmware WHILE retaining my untethered jailbroken status, Cydia, and the unlocked feature of the phone which allows me to use it without a data plan.

I've been told to simply update the phone in iTunes - will this retain all the things I mentioned above?

When I click on update iPhone, it says iTunes will "Verify this update with Apple" (or something along those lines) - what does this mean? Does this mean that Apple will know I'm using an iPhone w/o a data plan and will they then notify AT&T?

Lastly, the "backup" that you can create in iTunes is only information - Like, if I tried to back up from a 6.1.3 to a "backup" that was created with a phone on 5.1.1 firmware it would NOT restore the phone to firmware 5.1.1, correct?

Thank you so very much for your time, whoever is able to answer these questions. It means a lot to me. Thank you again, Sebastian

Comment: Try doing a search here for "[jailbreak update](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=jailbreak+update)" and you'll find a wealth of information from very similar questions - many of these questions should have appeared while you were composing this one.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'll try to answer one-by-one.

### Updating without loosing jailbreak

I'm afraid that it's no longer possible. The most recent iOS version - 6.1.3 - does not currently have a jailbreak available. You would keep all you info, but wouldn't keep your jailbreak - nor be able to get it back soon.

### Verify this update with Apple

It just means that Apple will sign your update and get stats on what kind of devices are updating, etc. Ever wondered where those percentages they get for the Keynote graphs are coming from? Now you know.

They won't tell AT&T. Even if they did, there is *nothing* wrong with using a phone without a data plan. Who cares, anyway?

### The Backup

Yes, it's only information - apps, app data, settings, pictures, etc.

Restoring to that backup would keep your data and put you on iOS 6.1.3.

Comment: Okay thank you for the prompt response! But I have the iPhone 3GS and the old bootrom - everything I've read up until now says that the this set up is permanently jailbroken. Have you heard about this or are you positive that a 3GS with old bootrom will not retain its jailbroken status? Thank you very much,

Comment: @Seb I'm pretty sure that an update to the most recent firmware will still kill your jailbreak. Might want to do some more reading, though, because I may be mistaken.

Comment: Alright so just to clarify for anyone else who may be dealing with my problem.      Update your iPhone (you may end up restoring it, instead, which is what I had to do because I had an error when I tried to update) to the most recent iOS (this is provided you have the qualifications that my iPhone did please check my original post!!!!) and download the most recent version of redsn0w (Keep in mind I'm working on a Mac; I used version 0.9.15b3). Open up the application and click on "Select IPSW"

Comment: Download the 6.0 ipsw from somewhere online (make sure you get the 3GS version) and select that for your selected IPSW. Now simply press the back button on the redsn0w application and click on jailbreak. Wolah!

Comment: And to clarify - with an old bootrom 3GS all new firmwares are untethered jailbreakable.

Comment: @Seb good for you!